# Using an argument as part of a variable

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments

I have a function which takes 1 argument. The function outputs several results and assigns them to a variable for later use. I would like to change the variable names using the argument but I am unsure how to do so. What I envison is something like what I have written below, but this returns a syntax error and I am not sure where to go from here.

Thank you!

```
def Get_Sums_Counts(Category):
    {Category}_Total_Count = len(Analyzed_Month[Analyzed_Month['age_cat'] == Category])
    return {Category}_Total_Count
    {Category}_Total_Sum = round(Analyzed_Month[Analyzed_Month['age_cat'] == Category].sum())
    return {Category}_Total_Sum
```

Comment: The best way to do something like this is generally to create a dictionary then assign the name you want as the key and the value as the value. Then you can manipulate the string key however you want.

Comment: Why do you actually want a dynamic variable name? What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a data set that consists of 6 groups. I want to write a function that will get me the sum and count of each group and save that amount to a unique variable based upon the functions argument so I can use it to populate a dataframe later.